# How to have separate folders for each app's static files in Django

Tags: python, django, project-structure, static-files

When I run `python manage.py collectstatic`, it puts all static files from different apps together in one location (`STATIC_ROOT`). I would like to have a separate folder within `STATIC_ROOT` for each app. For example static files from `app1/static` should go to `STATIC_ROOT/app1` and static files from `app2/static` should go to `STATIC_ROOT/app2`. One way to do this would be to create another subfolder, i.e. `app1/static/app1` - but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: I think adding the additional folder is the way to do it. It’s likely that you add another folder to [namespace templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#loader-types), why not also static resources?

Answer (score 2):

I usually put them all in one directory like the following just like how I work with templates:

```
MyProject/staticfiles/app1
MyProject/staticfiles/app2
MyProject/staticfiles/app3
```